# Single AND operator and multiple OR operators

Tags: select, sqlite

I wanted to select a record_id with a user_id of 1 and category_id can be 1, 2, or 3.
Every `SELECT` statement should return 1 record.

View my sample table here:

[image]

How do I do it in SQL? I tried this SQL statement:

```
SELECT record_id
FROM tbl_people
WHERE category_id=1 OR category=id=2 OR category_id=3
OR category_id=4 OR category_id=5 OR category_id=6 
AND user_id = 1;
```

...But it does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because in SQLite, the `AND` operator has a higher precedence than `OR` (see the Operators section on this [SQLite documentation page](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html))

This means that SQLite first evaluates the `category_id=6 AND user_id = 1` expression and then `OR`s its result with all the other `category_id` conditions.

Thus, your query returns all records where `category_id` is 1,2,3,4, or 5, or where `category_id` is 6 and `user_id` is 1.

You should add parentheses to force the `OR`s to be evaluated first:

```
SELECT record_id 
FROM tbl_people 
WHERE 
(
    category_id=1 OR 
    category_id=2 OR 
    category_id=3
)
AND user_id = 1;
```

Alternatively, you could use the SQL `IN` operator to make this more concise:

```
SELECT record_id 
FROM tbl_people 
WHERE category_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
AND user_id = 1;
```

*Also, note that you have a typo: in your `WHERE` clause there's a `category=id`, which should probably be `category_id`.*

**Update:** Here's a link to try out the query: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d7ad3/1